# Can we avoid using 'because' in these sentences?

Tags: prepositions

My question is if I can use "**that**" instead of "**because**" when I use "*to be*" construction?

> 1. The cellular phone set we purchased last year is awesome **that it has** many switches.
> 2. The cellular phone set we purchased last year is awesome **to have** many switches.

---

> 1. The car I bought last year changed **that it was** painted.
> 2. The car I bought last year changed **to be** painted.

Comment: @StoneyB I also agree with you. In these sentences **that** or **to have** doesn't mean **because**. But the problem is sometimes **that** can mean **because** for example in this sentence - *"I am glad that you came."*. So the question for a learner is when and at what circumstances **that** can mean **because**?

Comment: @Man_From_India Ah! Thank you, now I see what OP is driving at. Lemme rethink this.

Comment: Is there something different : The car I bought last year changed because it was painted.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite. Instead, use **in that** to mark it out.

> The cellular phone set we purchased last year is awesome, in that it has many switches.

or

> The car I bought last year changed, in that it was painted.

The commas aren't strictly required, but they help clarify.

---

The second one is a rather artificial example; it would be much more natural to say something like

> I had the car [that] I bought last year painted.

Comment: For the 4th example, another alternative is "The car I bought last year was repainted."

Comment: Or, even more simply, `I repainted my car.`

Comment: @webbcode: That implies that you did the repainting yourself, which is usually not the case. In informal speech that imprecision is sometimes okay, but it could still be confusing at times. I left that possibility out on purpose.

Comment: @NathanTuggy We're imprecise about such things all the time, though. `I painted my new house green` is far more common than `I paid someone else to paint my new house green`.

Comment: @webbcode: I guess that's one of those points of variation between native speakers, because I'd assume they literally meant they went out with a roller and a few buckets of paint from the hardware store and went at it.

Answer (score 1):

In the example sentences you quoted, neither **that** nor **to have** means **because**.

But **that** as a conjunction introduces a subordinate clause that often expresses the reason. But when?

The conjunction ***that*** may also introduce adverbial clauses of cause. Such clauses usually follow a main clause that is either a negative exclamation or a rhetorical question. The clause gives the reason for what is expressed in the exclamation or question.

> I'm not a cow **that** *you should expect me to eat grass*! 
>   Am I a cow **that** you should offer me grass?

The conjunction ***that*** is used to introduce adverbial clause of cause after adjectives (and past participles) that express emotion. The ***That*** is usually dropped in colloquial style.

> I'M glad (**that**) you came. 
>   He's sorry (**that**) he can't come. 
>   Aren't you thankful (**that**) your life has been spared? 
>   We're delighted (**that**) you can come. 
>   They're disappointed (**that**) you couldn't pay them a visit.

The use of an adverbial *that*-clause after a finite of an intransitive verb expressing an emotion is literary, not colloquial.

> I rejoiced **that** they have become friends again. 
>   She‥thought of them all the more **that** she was discouraged from enlarging on them.

Apart from that I think a good dictionary will tell when a word will take **that** in this sense. If not mentioned in dictionary, you can use this guide.